# SQL command to load image into SQLite DB

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database using SQLite Manager that will loaded up in an Android application.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to load an image from my pc into the database.

My table is structured like this:

```
artwork_table(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PAINTING_NAME TEXT, ARTIST TEXT, YEAR INTEGER, INFO TEXT, PAINTING_IMAGE BLOB)
```

My SQL command so far is

```
INSERT INTO artwork_table VALUES (1, "Mona Lisa", "Leonardo da Vinci",    "1517", "Real Good", readfile('C:\Users\Conor\Desktop\image.jpg'));
```

Is there not some function like readFile() or loadFile() I can pass my image's path to to load it in as data rather than a string?

I know how to load the image into the db from within the Android app but my goal is to have the db constructed beforehand.

Comment: I recommend storing a path to the image (in external storage, for instance) instead of the actual image itself and loading the image separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query worked when using the sqlite3 shell rather than the SQLite Manager Firefox.

I do not know the reason for this but here is my working statement in case anyone reading is wondering:

```
INSERT INTO artwork_table values(1, "Mona Lisa", "Leonardo da Vinci", 1517, "Real Good", readfile('C:\Users\Conor\Desktop\ml.jpg'));
```